# Проверяющая система на C#

Tags: c#, компилятор

Здравствуйте!

Столкнулся с проблемой использования чужих компиляторов в шарпе.

Задача: создать приложение, которое будет принимать программу (текстом, либо .exe) и прогонять ее по тестам (программа олимпиадная). Была мысль запускать компилятор нужного ЯП с помощью класса Process, перенаправить потоки ввода и вывода. Пробовал такое провернуть с питоном: открылась пустая консоль и через некоторое время закрылась - не работает.

Как можно решить проблему? Есть другие варианты проверки программ?

Comment: Ваш вариант звучит правильно. Вам нужно скомпилировать компилятором командной строки, и запустить полученную программу. Только позаботьтесь о том, чтобы запускать из-под пользователя с очень ограниченными правами доступа, ни в коем случае не из-под админа.

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам перенаправление ввода-вывода для компилятора. Чтобы получить сообщения об ошибках?

Comment: Делал похожее для Delphi. Разберитесь в аргументах, которые Вы передаёте компилятору, а также в том, все ли необходимые компоненты для компиляции установлены. Сначала добейтесь чтобы работал .bat - файл, потом - вызывайте из приложения.

Comment: Автор говорит не о перенаправлении ввода/вывода компилятора, а перенаправлении ввода/вывода скомпилированного приложения (чтобы проверять корректность его работы, подавая различные тестовые входные данные) Я прав?

Comment: Почему открылась и закрылось... тут нужно ваш код посмотреть. А так, да, идея правильная. Возможно вы забыли запустить свою программу после компиляции?

Comment: Я сначала получал поток для записи через Process.StandardInput, а чтобы с ним можно было что-то сделать (в т.ч. получить), необходимо было сообщить компилятору следующее: myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
я это подразумевал под перенаправлением потока, без этого не работает.

Comment: Пробовал просто запустить питон через Process.Start, окно открывается и в нем можно спокойно работать. Как только пытаюсь что-то сделать с потоками для того, чтобы записывать и читать программно, питон открывается пустой и через несколько секунд закрывается